# PlaceHolder + @Html.TextBox issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

### The goal

Apply, with success, the `placeholder` attribute for `@Html.Textbox` method.

### The problem

There is the following syntax on my application;

```
@Html.TextBox("term", new { placeholder = "What are you searching for?" })
```

But, when the `TextBox` is rendered, the `value` attribute of the `input` is `placeholder = "What are you searching for?"`. In other words, the `placeholder` attribute isn't applied as an attribute, but as an `input`'s `value`.

### Knowledge

I already searched about this question on Google and Stack Overflow, but until now, without success.

[This link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1779106.aspx/1) has a solution with the same syntax that I'm using, but when I pass the second parameter to `TextBox()`, it is rendered as a value and nothing happens with the third parameter (in our case, `new { placeholder = "something" }`).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're calling the [`string name, object value` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492984%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) of [that method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), so the second parameter is being taken as the `value`, not as `htmlAttributes`. You should use a different overload of the method, probably [`string name, object value, object htmlAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493049%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) by specifying an empty `value`:

```
@Html.TextBox("term", "", new { placeholder = "What are you searching for?" })
```

Comment: Bingo! That's exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try this for an empty @Html.TextBox

```
@Html.TextBox("CustomarName" ,null, new { @class = "form-control" , @placeholder = "Search With Customar Name" })
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a third param you need:

`@Html.TextBox("term", Model.SomeProperty, new { placeholder = "What are you searching for?" })`

The third param are any attributes you wish to include in the HTML output of the input field.